# Simple data structure in tiddlywiki

Tags: tiddlywiki5

I would like to use TW to keep track of the genealogy of some characters in a story.

I would like each character tiddler to have a couple of standard fields: father, mother, date-of-birth, sex, spouse, children

I am trying to figure out how to have some sort of form which it would create the fields automatically when I create a new character tiddler.

I found a couple of relevant tutorials but they are very outdated and in the end they confused me more.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Really late, however, check out Memory Keeper, a genealogical solution, that can be used to define characters or real people. You could define events (scenes) and places (settings)—all in TiddlyWiki.

You could write your story in this too.

http://craigsturgeon.com/mk/help/mkhelp.html

An example usage:

http://craigsturgeon.com/mk/example/Churchill-Example.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a characterTiddler, add those fields you said and add the characterTags Save it as $:/_newCharacter.

Then have a tiddler that is used to create new characters add a button that uses the characterTiddler as a template.

In the body of the Character Dashboard type:

```
//This will make a button that creates your tiddler//
<$button message="tm-new-tiddler" param="$:/_newCharacter">
New character
</$button>
//This is make a list of all tiddlers with the characterTags//
<<list-links "[!is[system]tag[characterTags]">>
```